# Excel formula, to pull if a cell (number) contains any of the numbers down a row and pulls data from the two columns to the right?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of numbers, Column F (This is just an example and there's maybe 500 numbers really listed down the column in actuality), as well as a list of numbers on the left (column A), along with data in columns b and C.

I'm trying to create a formula in Excel where, if cell F2 contains ANY of the number combinations (WITHIN the number in f2 itself) down Column A, then the number that pulls from Column A will then be put alongside the cell of f2 (in this case G2), and then the info to the right of column A (the cells to the right in columns b and C)....ALSO automatically go into column H and I (so it'd be h2 and I2).

[image]

So in the screenshot, the way itd work is that since the number in cell F2 contains "4234" within it, the "4234" would go next to the number and Column G (cell g2), and "Schnapple Inc" goes into Column H2, and then "SCHNPLE" goes into column I2.

I've been trying numerous formulas/'is number' combinations and I can't forget it out and don't want to have to tediously go through an entire set of numbers manually/trying to make it as easy as possible.

What formula could possibly configure this?

I'm trying to run this for every cell down Column F essentially.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? I've abbreviated the data to keep it simple.

[image: Sample data]

If that's what you want, this is one way:

```
G2: =IFERROR(IF(FIND(A2, F2), A2, ""), "")
H2: =IF($G2 <> "", B2, "")
I2: copy from H2
```

Copy `G2:I2` down to all rows.

In G2, FIND() does exactly that, it tries to find Prefix in Numbers. Wrap it in IFERROR() to leave the cell blank if it's not found. Otherwise Excel will show an error in that cell.